# Purpose of all the typeScript outDir options of angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

What is the purpose of having several `outDir` options in angular-cli?

I mean, there are:

- an `outDir` in `./.angular-cli.json` (which is the folder where the `ng build` put the built files to)
- an `outDir` in `./tsconfig.json` (which is obviously useless since this file is only extended by the `./src/tsconfig.xxx.json` files and they are overriding this option)
- an `outDir` in each `./src/tsconfig.xxx.json`(which never worked for me, I never saw any files generated in the assigned paths ...)

IMO, only the first one (from `./.angular-cli.json`) is used, the other are totally useless ...

But I imagine that the angular team did not specify them without a specific purpose.

Can anynbody explain that to me?

Comment: `outDir` in `.angular-cli.json` and `outDir` in `tsconfig.json` are completely separate. The first is where the build artifacts (webpack output bundles etc.) are places; you can serve the app from this directory. `tsconfig.json` is about `tsc` and where its output (`*.ts`) files go. Which `outDir` from which `tsconfig.*.json` is used is up to your particular configuration. You may want TS to compile test files into a different place, for example.

Comment: And the `tsconfig.xxx.json` are used inside your application. You could have several applications, and the first `tsconfig.json` would be the TypeScript configuration of your project, while the others would be the TypeScript configuration of your applications.

Comment: @torazaburo Thx. It makes sense. But I still dont get why I dont see any  files in the out-tsc folder (specified in tsconfig.xxx.json) when I use `ng serve` ... neither `ng test` by the way

Comment: They are intermediate artifacts. You would see them if you just ran the `tsc` command.